# X11 forwarding does not work if su to another user

Tags: rhel, x11, putty, xming

I have a Red Hat 7.3 server running XVnc.  On a Windows 10 desktop I have Putty and Xming installed.  Putty is configured for X11 forwarding.  When I SSH in as my standard/non-privileged user and launch an X application, it displays on my Windows 10 desktop without issue.

Now within same session, if I su to a more privileged account and try to run an X application, it fails with "error: can't open display".

In my standard user session if I echo $DISPLAY it is automatically set for me as "IP_ADDRESS:10.0".  Under my su session, $DISPLAY is null.  I tried exporting the DISPLAY variable to the same value but it now a different error appears: "PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorization protocol Error: Can't open display:server_IP:10.0".

How can I configure the X11 forwarding to work under the context of the other user?

Comment: The easiest way is to login with that user.

Comment: The only working & easiest solution is here:
https://superuser.com/questions/517878/why-cant-i-paste-into-xterm-xquartz

Answer (score 15):

The below steps should fix the issue for you.

Say it's working for `user1` and you want to use it for `user2`

For `user1`:

```
$ xauth list $DISPLAY
<output1>
$ echo $DISPLAY
<outoput2>
```

Switch to other user , i.e `user2`

```
$ xauth add <output1> 
$ export DISPLAY=<output2>
```

Try:

```
$ xclock
```

Comment: This works but it tedious. It would be nice to add a simple alias command that can do most of this work automatically somehow, at least not require copying and pasting. Wishful thinking on my part, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the the X11 display connection belongs to the user *with which you log in via SSH*.
`X11Forwarding` mechanism does not allow anyone else to use the display.

Fortunately, there's a workaround. After using `su` and become the othe user, issue this command:

```
xauth add $(xauth -f ~username/.Xauthority list | tail -1)
```

where `~username` is your original user, i.e. the user with which you connected to the server.

Obviously, this works if your new user has enough privileges to read `~username/.Xauthority` (i.e. if you `su` to `root` then there are no problems, if to another user it *might* not work and you need to check/modify permissions).

Comment: Thx! If you have no .Xauthority file for the target user and you are find with user1 security you can simply copy the auth file (for me it was from user1 to root): cp /home/user1/.Xauthority /root/

Comment: This looked promising. A single simple command.
The entire suggested command hangs for me, and so does this command (a sub-command of what the suggested command posted above) when run stand-alone: `xauth -f ~username/.Xauthority`. I assume this is some sort of permission issue. The second user is not root and I do not have admin privileges on this system, though I could submit a ticket to make a change. I am just not sure what needs to be changed. Do you? also, if I manage to solve this issue by myself, then I will leave another comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Slight change to Daniele's workaround:

```shell
xauth add $(xauth -i -f ~username/.Xauthority list | tail -1)
```

The `-i` option ignores locks; this way the `xauth list` command won't hang.